# Images dissapearing with hover effect

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I have created a grid of images with a hover effect. When you hover over the images it zooms in. It is working fine on safari but when I try it out on google chrome the images disappear when you hover over them instead of the zoom effect. I have provided my code below.

HTML :

```
    <body>

        <div class="message0">
            <img
                src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1312/0159/files/shutterstock_134800463.jpg?11249922432265530300" />
            Wakeup And Makeup <img
                src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1312/0159/files/shutterstock_134800463.jpg?11249922432265530300" />

        </div>


        <div class="masonry">
            <div class="fader0">
                <div class="item">
                    <img
                        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1312/0159/files/shutterstock_113634307.jpg?3027373344113436523" />
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="my-wrapper">
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="https://vipera-nyc.myshopify.com/collections/eyeshadow"><img
                        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1312/0159/files/Vipera_cae46bcd-7bd4-4ed6-ab7d-5970f5d6fa44.jpg?5440451544572147338" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="fader1">
                <div class="item">
                    <img
                        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1312/0159/files/shutterstock_313764047.jpg?453596164489734443" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img
                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1312/0159/files/HelloG-5.jpg?7272790211589801407" />
            </div>
            <div class="fader">
                <div class="item">
                    <img
                        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1312/0159/files/EYEScool.jpg?3027373344113436523" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img
                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1312/0159/files/shutterstock_91130072.jpg?3027373344113436523" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img
                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1312/0159/files/Makeup-2.jpg?7468684895134417704" />
            </div>
            <div class="my-wrapper">
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/ViperaNYC"><img
                        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1312/0159/files/Tweet_us_your_look.jpg?453596164489734443" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img
                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1312/0159/files/glosssssss_5c5c5520-ea20-4c78-8830-e633e5bb1083.jpg?1992342090983963689" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="my-wrapper">
                    <a
                        href="https://vipera-nyc.myshopify.com/collections/best-selling-products">
                        <img
                        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1312/0159/files/Best_Selling_Products-3.jpg?887070778965157300" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>




        </div>



    </body>
```

CSS:

```
.item img { /* Masonry bricks or child elements */
    background-color: #eee;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: 100%;
}

.itemkat img {
 background-color: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  width:100%;

}

.grid {
  column-count: 3;

    -webkit-column-gap: -10px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: -10px; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: -10px;
  line-height:100%;
}

.grid-item{
  background-color: #eee;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: 100%;
}


.message0
{

  display:center;
  font-size:30px;
}



.my-wrapper {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.my-wrapper:hover img {

  opacity:0.2;
}


* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  position: relative;

 /* margin: 0%;  /*makes left margin closer */
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 470px;
}
.item img {
  max-width: 100%; /*reduces space between images */
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.item:hover img {
    overflow: hidden;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);

}


.message0 {
  font-family: Brush Script MT ;
  font-size:120px;
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

I have provided a fiddle. ***IT WORKS ON OTHER INTERNET BROWSERS BUT NOT GOOGLE CHROME WHICH IS THE PROBLEM****
https://jsfiddle.net/getMecoffee56/o11hmwek/1/

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: @oooyaya https://jsfiddle.net/getMecoffee56/o11hmwek/1/ here is the fiddle! I tried it on safari and it works fine but on google chrome it is not

Comment: @JunKang it does not work on google chrome though only on other internet browsers.

Comment: `.item img { backface-visibility: hidden;}`

Comment: @Morpheus that worked ! Thank you :)